# Change name of element when serialize() is called

Tags: jquery, serialization

Is there any way to modify what the name of the element getting serialized is, but only in the serialized data?  I might not be asking that right, so here's what I mean.

Meaning, if I have a control like:

```
<asp:dropdownlist id="ddTest" runat="server">
    <asp:listitem value="1" name="1" />
    <asp:listitem value="2" name="2" />
</asp:dropdownlist>
```

And I serialize it:

```
var x = $("form").serialize();
```

x would come out like:

```
ddTest=2
```

So, my question is, without changing the name of the control, how can I get x to come out like:

```
TestID=2
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Serialize does *not* grab the IDs of the form elements. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: You could just modify the output string from .serialize();

Comment: What I'm trying to do is make a filter for a datatable that's returned to a jqGrid.  A field it can filter on would be "TestID = 2".  I could do a select/case statement to check what the serialized data is, then change the filter string accordingly, but I was hoping to find a quicker way.

Answer (score 3):

Here's something that might work.

1. Use [`serializeArray`](http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/) to serialize the form into an array that looks like this:

   ```
   [{ name: "field_name", value: "field_value" }, ...]
   ```
2. Modify the correct `name` property by looping over the resulting array.
3. Use [`$.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param) to stringify the array properly.

   ```
   $("#testform").submit(function (e) {
       var values = $(this).serializeArray()
           , found = false
           , i
           , serialized;

       e.preventDefault();

       for (i = 0; i < values.length && !found; i++) {
           if (values[i].name == "field1") { 
               // or whatever field you'd like to replace
               values[i].name = "new_field_name";
               found = true;
           }
       }

       // serialized string with new names.
       serialized = $.param(values);
   });
   ```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/X6SV8/

Answer (score 0):

You can try cloning the node, changing the information in the cloned node, serializing it, and then deleting the clone.

http://api.jquery.com/clone/